# Extract minimum and maximum date using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

After joining of 4 datafarmes with min and max dates per subgroup (a, b, c, d, etc...), the final dataframe has the following columns:

```
Id   a_min_date_df1  a_max_date_df1  a_min_date_df2   a_max_date_df2  a_min_date_df3    a_max_date_df3  a_min_date_df4   a_max_date_df4
1    2014-01-01      2014-01-10       NA              NA               NA                NA             2014-02-20       2014-05-01
2    2014-02-01      2014-02-10       NA              NA               2015-02-20       2015-03-01             NA               NA
```

For some Id I have only min and max dates available from 1 of 2 dataframes instead of all 4 dataframes.

I want to add:

- a new column that has the minimum date of min-date columns per subgroup (a, b, c, d, etc...)
- a new column that has the maximum date of max-date columns per subgroup (a, b, c, d, etc...)
- a column that calculates the difference between the new max and min date, and if the difference is more than 365 days, 
  than I want to adjust the new min and max date and replace them by the orginal dates: a_min_date_df1 and a_max_date_df1

I have tried this and it works, but the df has more than 500 subgroups which I could not do manually for each.

```
mutate(df, a_min= pmin(a_min_date1_df1, a_min_date1_df2, a_min_date1_df3, a_min_date1_df4, na.rm=TRUE), 
a_max= pmax(a_max_date1_df1, a_max_date1_df2, a_max_date1_df3, a_max_date1_df4, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I started to replace the column names with mutate(df, a_min= pmin(setdiff(starts_with("a_"), ends_with(min_date), na.rm=TRUE), a_max= pmax(setdiff(starts_with("a_"), ends_with(min_date), na.rm=TRUE)) 
This did not work for me. All suggestions are welecom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Id), list(~ as.Date(as.character(.)))) %>%
  mutate(pmx = pmax(!!! syms(select(., contains("max")) %>% names), na.rm = T),
         pmn = pmin(!!! syms(select(., contains("min")) %>% names), na.rm = T),
         diffr = pmx - pmn,
         pmx = case_when(diffr > 365 ~ a_max_date_df1, TRUE ~ pmx),
         pmn = case_when(diffr > 365 ~ a_min_date_df1, TRUE ~ pmn)
  )
```

Output:

```
  Id a_min_date_df1 a_max_date_df1 a_min_date_df2 a_max_date_df2 a_min_date_df3 a_max_date_df3 a_min_date_df4
1  1     2014-01-01     2014-01-10           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>     2014-02-20
2  2     2014-02-01     2014-02-10           <NA>           <NA>     2015-02-20     2015-03-01           <NA>
  a_max_date_df4        pmx        pmn    diffr
1     2014-05-01 2014-05-01 2014-01-01 120 days
2           <NA> 2014-02-10 2014-02-01 393 days
```

Comment: Thank you arg0naut! I got the following error.                                                        Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: This means the code will run once you get your dates in a good `Date` format. Unfortunately cannot help more without knowing your exact data frame which you can provide with `dput`.

Comment: I want to remove NA that were copied to pmax from  a_max_date_df1. I tried this case_when (diffr>  365 & !is.na(a_max_date_df1) ~ a_max_date_df1, TRUE ~ pmx), but got an error: Error in Ops.Date(left) : unary ! not defined for "Date" objects

Comment: Cannot reproduce it - can you share relevant data via dput, that'd be great

Comment: After trying a few times, case_when seems also to work if I add !is.na.     
 case_when (diffr> 365 & !is.na(a_max_date_df1) ~ a_max_date_df1, TRUE ~ pmx).